Arrays in pinia seem to be not reactive
I have problems in pinia with reactivity of an array of objects which have an array of objects themselves.
In pinia I have an array of voyage-objects. A voyage has an array of leg-objects.
If I add a leg to the currently displayed voyage the view does not rerender.
I made a simple example on Pinia Playground
It consists of four files:
<!-- App.vue -->
<script setup lang="ts">
import LegList from './LegList.vue';
import { useVoyageStore } from './store'
const voyageStore = useVoyageStore()
</script>

<template>
  <main>
    <p>Number of legs: {{voyageStore.num}} {{voyageStore.getCurrentVoyage.legs.length}}</p>
    <div>
      <LegList :key="voyageStore.currentVoyageId" />
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

// store.ts
import { ref, computed } from 'vue'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export class Voyage {
  static nextId = 1
  public id: number
  public name: string
  public legs = [] as Leg[]

  public constructor(id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id
    this.name = name
  }

  public newLeg = () => {
    const leg = new Leg(Leg.nextId++, this.id, 'newLeg')
    this.legs.push(leg)
    console.log('Leg added')
  }

  public removeLeg = () => {
    this.legs.pop()
  }
}

export class Leg {
  static nextId = 1
  public id: number
  public voyage_id: number
  public name:string
 
  public constructor(id: number, voyage_id: number, name: string) {
    this.id = id
    this.voyage_id = voyage_id
    this.name = name
  }
}

export const useVoyageStore = defineStore('voyages', () => {
  const voyages = ref([] as Voyage[])
  voyages.value.push(new Voyage(Voyage.nextId++, 'newVoyage'))
  const currentVoyageId = ref(0)
  const num = ref(0)

  const getCurrentVoyage = computed(() => {return voyages.value[currentVoyageId.value]})

  const addVoyage = (voyage: Voyage) => {
    voyages.value.push(voyage)
  }

  const removeVoyage = (id: number) => {
    const index = voyages.value.findIndex((x) => x.id == id)
    if (index > -1) {
      voyages.value.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }

  const newLeg = () => {
    getCurrentVoyage.value.newLeg()
    num.value++
  }

  return {
    voyages,
    currentVoyageId,
    getCurrentVoyage,
    addVoyage,
    removeVoyage,
    newLeg,
    num
  }
})

<!-- LegList.vue -->
<script setup lang="ts">
import VoyageLeg from './VoyageLeg.vue'
import { useVoyageStore } from './store'
const voyageStore = useVoyageStore()
</script>

<template>
  <h3>Voyage {{ voyageStore.currentVoyageId }} with {{ voyageStore.getCurrentVoyage.legs.length }} legs</h3>
  <button @click="voyageStore.newLeg">Add Leg</button>
  <div :key="voyageStore.currentVoyageId">
    <VoyageLeg v-for="item in voyageStore.getCurrentVoyage.legs" :key="item.id" :leg="item"> </VoyageLeg>
  </div>
</template>

<!-- VoyageLeg.vue -->
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Leg } from './store'

defineProps<{
  leg: Leg
}>()
</script>

<template>
      <div style="border:1px">
          <input id="voyageleg-name" type="text" autocomplete="off" :value="leg.name">
      </div>
</template>

Pressing the button does add a leg into the array of legs of the current voyage as can be seen by the numbers at the top but the leg-components do not show.
Is there something I can do to make it work?

Classes don't conform well to Vue's reactivity system. See this answer.  Your problem is definitely related to the use of classes, and you should likely refactor your code to not have them.
